# Error when extracting data from JSON webhook

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-3.8

I am not able to access the data from the event in the python function

I am trying to get the name from the JSON

```
def handler(event, context):
     
    resp =  event
    user_name = resp['body']['user']['name']
```

but I get the following error

```
ERROR] TypeError: string indices must be integers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 28, in handler
    user_name = resp['body']['user']['name']
```

Comment: maybe `resp` is already the body. try using `resp['repository']['name']` and tell me the result.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: bring more code to the question. cant debug with just 2 lines of code. please learn to bring more details or bring more code.

Comment: I am just trying to execute these 2 lines of code, there nothing other than this

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `resp` is of `string` type. load your response in `JSON` before accessing it.

```
import json
resp = json.loads(resp)
```

Comment: I am getting a Type Error for the json.loads(resp)
```
 TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Comment: use `json.load`

Comment: It say AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'. when I use resp = json.load(event)

Comment: If I use json.dumps() for the above error I get the same error as in the top of my question TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @AbilashJayanandan find out the type of resp by using type(resp)

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me. The event body should be retrieved first

```
import json

def handler(event, context):
     resp =  json.loads(event["body"])
     user_name = event['user']['name']
```